# Error page when adding an already existing member to mailchimp list?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, backend, nodemon

I've been doing Angela Yu's course for last few weeks and tried to get Mailchimp API to work like she does in it. Unfortunately, Mailchimp has changed since then so I found the API reference on my own and copied it into my code. Works perfectly until I'm trying to get an error page.

```
app.post("/", function(req, res){
    
const listId = "72fc49b92f";

const subscribingUser = {
  firstName: (req.body.firstName),
  lastName: (req.body.lastName),
  email: (req.body.email)
};

async function run() {
  const response = await mailchimp.lists.addListMember(listId, {
    email_address: subscribingUser.email,
    status: "subscribed",
    merge_fields: {
      FNAME: subscribingUser.firstName,
      LNAME: subscribingUser.lastName
    }
  });

  console.log(
    `Successfully added contact as an audience member. The contact's id is ${
      response.id
    }.`
  );
}

run();


});
```

I tried to use if

```
if (reponse.statusCode === 400) {
    res.send("This member already exists);
```

in any possible place in the code but none of that worked.

Answer (score 0):

Since a lot changed to the course, taking a look directly to the API is good decision. If you check [here](https://mailchimp.com/developer/marketing/api/list-members/add-member-to-list/) and expand the "Add members to list" section, it shows the object that the Mailchimp API returns for errors

Sample error response from the said link:

```json
{
  "type": "https://mailchimp.com/developer/marketing/docs/errors/",
  "title": "Resource Not Found",
  "status": 404,
  "detail": "The requested resource could not be found.",
  "instance": "995c5cb0-3280-4a6e-808b-3b096d0bb219"
}
```

With that, just replace `response.statusCode === 400` with `response.status === 404` like this:

```js
  async function run() {
    const response = await mailchimp.lists.addListMember(listId, {
      email_address: subscribingUser.email,
      status: "subscribed",
      merge_fields: {
        FNAME: subscribingUser.firstName,
        LNAME: subscribingUser.lastName
      }
    });

    if (response.status === 404) {
      //Error 400 status from response
      res.send("This member already exists");
    } else {
      //Other stuff to do without error 404 status
      console.log(`Successfully added contact as an audience member. The contact's id is ${response.id}.`);
      res.send("Thank you for subscribing!")
    }
  }
```

Catching errors is good, but I suggest that we validate the correct response first with an `if(response.status === 'subscribed')`, and then catch other errors not just the `400`

Comment: It didn't really work, /* (response.status) */ targets only the "status" property in the const and if the member is already in the list, the app will crash and I have no idea how to catch the error.